# Why is the JOptionPane not being displayed after the client has established a connection to the server?

Tags: java, sockets

After starting the server and the client, the processInput method which is inside the Client class does not get called. I tried to use the debugger to see if I could find out what was causing the problem but I was not able to. What I observed while using the debugger is that the (is), ObjectInputStream instance is not being initialized. Whenever I am at this line with the debugger, I am not able to proceed any further with the debugging process.

This is the code for the client.

```
ObjectInputStream is;
ObjectOutputStream os;
Socket socket;

public ClientEmp(){
    try {
        socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 4200);
        is = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        os = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void processInput(){
    String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name: ");
    try {
        os.writeObject(str);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            ClientEmp cli = new ClientEmp();
            cli.processInput();
        }
    });
}
```

This is the code for the Server.

```
private Socket socket;
private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private ObjectInputStream is;
private ObjectOutputStream os;

public ServerEmp() {
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4200);
        System.out.println("Server Started");
        while (true) {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();

            getStream();

            System.out.println("Connection made to the server");

            try {
                String str = (String) is.readObject();
                System.out.println(str);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void getStream(){
    try {
        is = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        os = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public static void main(String args[]) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new ServerEmp();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. The problem was with the order in which the ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream instance were being initialized on both the client and the server.